# kivy: How to connect Imagebutton?

Tags: python, button, kivy

Here's my code. I want to add **Open_file** in button.

```
<ImgButton>
    id: open_file
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: dp(5)
        ImageButton:
            source:'.\download (1).jfif'
            pos: 50,450
            size_hint : .8,.4
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: True
            on_press: root.button()
```

How can I connect button?

```
class ImgButton(Screen):
  pass
```

Can anyone help me how does all this code?

Comment: since it's a button    you should write   `class ImageButton(Button)` . You are creating a subtype of the button family

Comment: @VisheshMangla I have used `class ImageButton(Button)` but I have got `ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245242/kivy-uix-screenmanager-screenmanagerexception-screenmanager-accepts-only-screen

Comment: snippet not found

Comment: Nice job, happy to hear that you found the bug!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution in connect Imagebutton... ImgButton.kv

```
<ImgButton>
    id: open_file
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: dp(5)
        on_release: root.manager.current='Open_file'
        ImageButton:
            source:'.\download (1).jfif'
            pos: 50,450
            size_hint : .8,.4
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: True
            on_press: root.button()
```

ImgButton.py

```
class ImgButton(Screen):
   pass
```